# SQL Query Foreign query help needed

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

Need help to write a SQL query:

I have two tables:

```
users:(id, name,role)
orders:(id,sup_id,user_id)
```

I want to use a inner join to display a list of all today's orders in the below format:

```
User_id,sup_name,order_id,
```

I tried:

```
select users.id,orders.id, from orders inner join ON users.id=orders.id
```

Problem: I don't know, how to map sup_id from the user table and display the same.

Comment: How do you know what today's order are?  And where does `sup_name` come from?

Comment: There is no `sup_id` in the user table according to your table descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to join `orders(sup_id)` on `users(id)`. If so, that would be:

```
select o.user_id, u.name sup_name, o.id order_id
from orders o 
inner join users u ON u.id = o.sup_id
```

Comment: actually, order table contains all records and join should be on u.id = o.user_id, please help me select user.name(supplier name) for all orders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the `join` conditions, but also filter on the current date.  That is a bit unclear, but something like:

```
select o.*, u.name as sup_name
from users u join
     orders o
     on u.id = o.sup_id
where o.orderdate >= current_date and
      o.order_date < current_date + interval '1 day';
```